# Ignore horizontal safe area with vertical ScrollView

Tags: swiftui, scrollview

I am trying to create a layout with multiple horizontal ScrollViews inside a vertical ScrollView, similar to the template picker in Apple's Pages app. I would like the content of the horizontal ScrollViews to be visible beyond the safe area. However I seem to be unable to get the content of the vertical ScrollView outside the horizontal safe insets. This is visible when iPhones with a notch are used in landscape orientation.

I have tried adding negative padding to the content of the vertical ScrollView. This kind of works, but creates issues when using the device in portrait mode.

Below example code shows the issue. I would expect the rectangles to be visible in beyond the safe area when scrolling horizontally, but they get clipped. How can I make them visible beyond the safe area?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                HStack {
                    Rectangle()
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 300)
                    
                    Rectangle()
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 300)
                    
                    Rectangle()
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 300)
                }
            }   .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.horizontal)
        }   .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.horizontal)
    }
}
```

Comment: With Xcode 12/ iOS 14 works *as is*.

Comment: @Asperi dropping support for < iOS 14 *is* an option. But I really hoped there would be an acceptable workaround...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect when the device's orientation changes and adapt your view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.verticalSizeClass) var verticalSizeClass

    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if verticalSizeClass == .compact {
                content.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.horizontal)
            } else {
                content
            }
        }
    }

    var content: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                HStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .frame(width: 200, height: 300)

                    Rectangle()
                        .frame(width: 200, height: 300)

                    Rectangle()
                        .frame(width: 200, height: 300)
                }
            }
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.horizontal)
    }
}
```

Comment: Wrapping the vertical scrollView in a view (content) does the trick! Unfortunately, creating a different view for a different size class gives a very ugly transition when rotating the device. And without the different view per size class the insets mess up when transitioning from landscape to portrait...